# How can I deduct the Badge Counter on iOS by one every time the user reads a Push Notification from the tray?

Tags: xtify

I'm using the Xtify plug in through Application Craft.

After looking at Xtify's help page: http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/PhoneGap+Cordova+for+iOS+Xtify+Integration+Guide

at the section: **To Manage the Badge Count**

I found a set of functions to control the Badge Number.

But it is not clear from these functions, how can I deduct the Badge Counter by one, after the user reads one of the received notifications. For the moment I can only completely clear all notifications from the Tray (and the Badge Counter disappears).

But if the user has received 4 unread notifications, the badge counter is set to 4.
Then if the user reads one of these notifications, the badge counter is still stuck to "4".
I want to simply reduce the counter by one and remove only that "read" notication from the tray and not ALL notifications.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are set/get badge javascript methods that will set and get the native iOS badge counts. However, this will only work if the Xtify native objective C plugin class is included in the application craft platform and compiled with the application.  The javascript functions interact with the underlying Xtify xCode/obj-c functions.

That would be step 9-14 on this page:
http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/PhoneGap+Cordova+for+iOS+Xtify+Integration+Guide

Likely you will have to contact AC directly to support the Xtify native phonegap cordova plugin.